# Jersey MultiPartRequest receiving null

Tags: java, spring-boot, jax-rs, deserialization, jersey-2.0

I am trying to build a multipart request from a client using MultipartEntitybuilder:

```
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            builder.addTextBody(MULTIPART_ID,
                    id,ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            builder.addTextBody(DOCT, doc,ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            final InputStreamBody fileBody = new InputStreamBody(cachedStream,
                    ContentType.create(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));
            builder.addPart(CONTENT_PART, fileBody);
            builder.addTextBody(OVERWRIT_PERMIT, String.valueOf(preventOverWrite),ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);


            final HttpPut putMethod= new HttpPut(url);
        //    putMethod.setHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data"
            putMethod.setEntity(builder.build());
            final CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(storeMethod);
```

The Resource Class reading this is as follows:

```
@Path("/somePath")
    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public Response uploadFunction(@FormDataParam(value="id")  String id, @FormDataParam(value="doc") String doc,@FormDataParam(value="content") InputStream content,
                                        @FormDataParam(value="overwrite") Boolean flag) throws SomeException {
```

I am using spring boot with Jersey2 . At this step when i try to read any of these I am getting null values for all these parameters. and hence the response gets an internal server error.

I have also added :

```
register(MultiPartFeature.class);
```

to both the client and server application.

Additionally Also added the dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Could someone please point out what am i missing ?Do i need to create an object instead of using @FormDataParam for the server? I have searched a lot over correctly using multipart, but I cannot fix it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this after using a Decoder. Also needed a DTO of the representative object.So the above resource class was updated to

```
@Path("/somePath")
    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public Response uploadFunction(FormDataMultiPart input){
    Map<String, List<FormDataBodyPart>> bodyParts = input.getFields();
    bodyParts.get("id").stream().findFirst().ifPresent(id-> dtoObject.setId(id.getValue()));
    }
```

Similarly for other fields you can retrieve the value as well.